# C++ reference vs local variable

Tags: c++, memory, reference

Assume I have some object, such as:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<double> > some_map;
```

Simple question: is it more efficient to do the following

```
std::vector<double> vec = some_map[some_index];
```

or referencing it

```
std::vector<double>& vec = some_map[some_index];
```

Can anyone explain in short what typically happens behind the scenes here?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two have different semantics, and aren't interchangeable.
The first gives you a copy, which you can modify however you
wish, without changing anything in the map.  The second gives
you a reference to the data element in the map; any
modifications modify the contents of the map.  Also, although
probably not an issue, be aware that if the map is destructed
before the reference goes out of scope, the reference will
dangle.

With regards to performance, it depends on what's in the vector,
and what you do with it later; in most cases, the reference will
probably have better performance, but you shouldn't worry about
it until the profiler says you have to.  (And if you do use the
reference, make it `const`, unless you really do want to be able
to modify the contents of the map.)

Answer (score 4):

Creating a reference is more efficient, but you should note that these two statements are different in semantics and have different behaviors.

If you do

```
std::vector<double> vec = some_map[some_index];
```

The copy constructor of `std::vector` is called to copy the whole vector `some_map[some_index]` into `vec`. In this way, you get a fresh new vector `vec`. They are independent objects and any changes to `vec` does not affect the original map.

If you use

```
std::vector<double>& vec = some_map[some_index];
```

then `vec` refers directly to `some_map[some_index]` and copy is avoided. However, be aware that if you later change `vec`, the change will be reflected in both `vec` and `some_map[some_index]` since they refer to the same object. To prevent undesirable changes, it is safer to use a const reference:

```
const std::vector<double>& vec = some_map[some_index];
```

Comment: The difference in the semantics is probably more important than any difference in performance.

Comment: 2 Different implementations have 2 different objectives, declaring the variable by value enable you to modify the variable without the risk of modifying the original value.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing is much more efficient, both in terms of memory used and cpu cycles. Your first line of code makes a copy of the vector, which includes copying every item in the vector. In the second, you're simply referring to the existing vector. No copies are made.

Comment: Thank you as well, James was just a bit faster :-)